# На что влияет сортировка в индексе?

Tags: sql

Вот можно построить индекс с разными сортировками(по возрастанию/по убыванию).

Я же правильно понимаю, что эти сортировки никак не влияют на конечное дерево, а лишь влияют на порядок в котором дерево будет обходится при поиске?

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под "конечное дерево"?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц наверное, дерево которое будет в конечном итоге построено

Comment: Голосуют за закрытие, видимо, те, кто не знает sql и не слышал про индексы? Нормальный вопрос же